# only 8192 bytes data only received from Stream socket using php

Tags: php, sockets, fread

```
    $ip="****";     //Set the TCP IP Address to connect too
$port="8088";        //Set the TCP PORT to connect too
$command="hi";       //Command to run
$req['path'] = $path;
$post = json_encode($req);
//Connect to Server
$socket = stream_socket_client("tcp://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, 30);

if($socket) {
 //Start SSL
 stream_set_blocking ($socket, true);
 stream_socket_enable_crypto ($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT);
 stream_set_blocking ($socket, false);

 //Send a command
 fwrite($socket, $post);


 $buf = null;
 //Receive response from server. Loop until the response is finished
 while (!feof($socket)) {
  $buf .= fread($socket, 20240);
 } 



 //close connection
 fclose($socket);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($buf); exit;

 //echo our command response
 return json_decode($buf);
}
```

This is my code. 
this code is working fine for below 8192 bytes value. but
it can't get the above 8192 bytes what i need to get above this bytes.
because i need get the more bytes of data here 
Please provide one example

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried with stream_set_timeout but got the same problem. i need the SSL connection to send the data for this purpose i use this code if anyone have other idea please share it. or give the solution to get the full data from fread

Comment: Have you tried any examples  from the internet to get something that works? e.g. [here](http://blog.leenix.co.uk/2011/05/howto-php-tcp-serverclient-with-ssl.html) and [here](http://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-use-ssl-sockets-php).

Comment: Yeah i got this code from this example, i face this issue on this code

Comment: till now i did'nt got the solution. one thing i need to add here in the localhost i got the full output data in the live server only the 8192 bytes output received. anyone have idea about this please share it

Answer (score 1):

When you write to a network stream, a single call to `fwrite()` does not necessary writes the whole data.

There is a note at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php which says:

> Writing to a network stream may end before the whole string is
>   written. Return value of fwrite() may be checked:

```php
<?php
function fwrite_stream($fp, $string) {
    for ($written = 0; $written < strlen($string); $written += $fwrite) {
        $fwrite = fwrite($fp, substr($string, $written));
        if ($fwrite === false) {
            return $written;
        }
    }
    return $written;
}
?>
```

You may wonder, where does this 8192 number come from.

It seems like this is the default chunk size for the stream.
You can check and change chunk size via [stream_set_chunk_size()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-chunk-size.php) function

Answer (score 0):

You have set the socket in non-blocking mode:

```
stream_set_blocking ($socket, false);
```

In non-blocking mode, you should wait for data availability on the socket before trying to perform read operations. PHP provides [`stream_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) function for this purpose.

So you should whether make the socket blocking, or handle events with `stream_select`.